# Kotlin: How to get a capture group of the first line that matches?

Tags: regex, kotlin, sequence

1. Starting with a lineSequence
2. I'd like to test if a Regex matches, and if so, get the first match
3. Furthermore, I'd like to return a capturing group from that Regex match

If I didn't care, I'd do a "first" on the lineSequence, and if it existed, re-run the regex.

```
val possibleMatch = input.lineSequence().first { myRegex.matches(it) }
```

... but I want to be kotlin-cool and not have to re-run the regex.  Should I use a map to a MatchGroup and filter out nulls?  Feels more verbose than it could be...

```
input.lineSequence()
.mapNotNull { myRegex.find(it) }
.map { it.groupValues[1] }
.first()
```

Comment: It might feel more verbose, but your intent seems very clear to me (subjective, yes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simplify it to single `.mapNotNull { ... }`:

```
input.lineSequence()
    .mapNotNull { regex.find(it)?.groupValues?.get(1) }
    .first()
```

If `.find(it)` returns `null`, the value will still be dropped from the sequence, and otherwise it will be processed in the same call.